# Why I can't assign an ip to LWP::UserAgent?

Tags: perl, ip, lwp-useragent

I have a script that should be able to do some calls to a service with different IP addresses.  My code works when I don't set any ip to my calls, I wrote a function to assign an IP to the object before doing calls, but it returns an error:

```
Can't locate object method "local_address" via package "LWP::UserAgent"
```

This is my functions structure:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Headers;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use URI::Escape;
use HTML::LinkExtor;

# set user agent object values
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
$ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.10) Gecko/20050716 Firefox/1.0.6');
push @{ $ua->requests_redirectable }, 'POST';
$ua->cookie_jar({});


sub set_caller_ip {
    my($set_ip_address) = @_;

    $ua->local_address("$set_ip_address");
    return 1;
}


sub test_caller_ip {

    my $req = new HTTP::Request('GET', 'http://whatismyip.org/');
    $req->headers->push_header('Connection','Keep-Alive');
    $req->headers->push_header('Accept','text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8');
    my $res = $ua->request($req) or die "$!";

    return $res->content();
}
```

And this is the way that I call them:

```
set_caller_ip($caller_ip_address);

$caller_ip_tested = test_caller_ip();
print "\$caller_ip_tested=".$caller_ip_tested."\n";die;
```

Do you know what's the issue?!

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `local_address` attribute was added in [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) version 5.834.  Could you be using an older version?

Try:

```
use LWP::UserAgent 5.834; # need local_address
```

(Whenever I specify a minimum version for a module, I try to add a brief comment explaining why that's the minimum version.)

Comment: you are absolutely right... Thanks man! I was struggling with this issue for 3 hours... And actually I'm not a sys admin so now I should learn how to upgrade this module!!! anyway... thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Monica, when you see that `Can't locate object method` message, there's basically 3 options:  you've misspelled the method name, you've got the wrong kind of object, or the version of the module doesn't match the documentation you're reading (and the API changed).

Comment: I didn't mention that I'm new in perl, because I thought it is  obvious! It is a little weird error message though! anyway, I really appreciate your help for telling all the possible reasons! That's great, it will save my time in future! MANY THANKS :)

Answer (score 1):

@cjm has already answered the question about your error, but it might be useful to note an alternative for older versions of LWP::UserAgent.

There's an un- (or at least under-) documented feature of LWP::Protocol::http that lets you set "extra socket options".  I'm doing this in my code (using 5.824), and it works:

```
@LWP::Protocol::http::EXTRA_SOCK_OPTS = { LocalAddr => "10.11.12.13" };
```

The same code in LWP/Protocol/http.pm seems to also exist in a much older LWP installed with perl 5.8 on an old RHEL4 system, so it's been around a while...  :-)

Comment: How do you check if the request is coming from the specified source IP?